# What packages are needed for ubuntu:jammy docker image to connect mongodb in kubernetes?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm building web application which will be deployed in kubernetes.

Web application is Next project and interacts with daemon that requires following packages.

```
libeigen3-dev libboost-all-dev libopencv-dev libpcl-dev zlib1g-dev libflann-dev libqhull-dev libsnappy-dev libicu-dev libglib2.0-dev libbsd-dev libpcre3-dev libbson-dev libmongoc-dev libcgal-dev
```

Both web application and linux daemon is in one node(deployment) and docker image is based on ubuntu:jammy.
Mongo db is in 2 replica nodes (statefulset).
To access statefulset resources, kubernetes use dns address instead of IP address, in my case, mongo-0.mongodb, mongo-1.mongodb, etc.

The problem is web application can't connect to mongodb.
I  wrote demo react application in docker image based on node:16-alpine, and it connected successfully to mongo-db.
It seems that there's something missing package in ubuntu:jammy.

I listed all packages in node:16-alpine image using `apk list` command.
The result is as follows.

```
alpine-baselayout-3.4.3-r1 x86_64 {alpine-baselayout} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
alpine-baselayout-data-3.4.3-r1 x86_64 {alpine-baselayout} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
alpine-keys-2.4-r1 x86_64 {alpine-keys} (MIT) [installed]
apk-tools-2.14.0-r2 x86_64 {apk-tools} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
busybox-1.36.1-r0 x86_64 {busybox} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
busybox-binsh-1.36.1-r0 x86_64 {busybox} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
ca-certificates-bundle-20230506-r0 x86_64 {ca-certificates} (MPL-2.0 AND MIT) [installed]
libc-utils-0.7.2-r5 x86_64 {libc-dev} (BSD-2-Clause AND BSD-3-Clause) [installed]
libcrypto3-3.1.1-r1 x86_64 {openssl} (Apache-2.0) [installed]
libgcc-12.2.1_git20220924-r10 x86_64 {gcc} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND LGPL-2.1-or-later) [installed]
libssl3-3.1.1-r1 x86_64 {openssl} (Apache-2.0) [installed]
libstdc++-12.2.1_git20220924-r10 x86_64 {gcc} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND LGPL-2.1-or-later) [installed]
musl-1.2.4-r0 x86_64 {musl} (MIT) [installed]
musl-utils-1.2.4-r0 x86_64 {musl} (MIT AND BSD-2-Clause AND GPL-2.0-or-later) [installed]
scanelf-1.3.7-r1 x86_64 {pax-utils} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
ssl_client-1.36.1-r0 x86_64 {busybox} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
zlib-1.2.13-r1 x86_64 {zlib} (Zlib) [installed]`
```

There's nothing about network or dns(except ssl_client, but so far my protocol is limited in http).
By default, ubuntu:jammy docker image doesn't recognize ping, nslookup command lines. To enable dns lookup, I installed dnsutils package in my docker image.
Inside pods, I could get the IP address of mongodb pods using

```
nslookup mongo-0.mongodb
Name:   mongo-0.mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.1.134.26
```

But still I can't connect to mongodb from Next application(node mongo client).
Here is error message.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-0
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/oes/oes-web/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'mongo-0:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'mongo-0:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 218614109,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-0
            at connectionFailureError (/usr/oes/oes-web/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:367:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/oes/oes-web/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-0
              at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
            errno: -3008,
            code: 'ENOTFOUND',
            syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
            hostname: 'mongo-0'
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'rs0',
    maxElectionId: ObjectId {
      [Symbol(id)]: Buffer(12) [Uint8Array] [
        127, 255, 255, 255, 0,
          0,   0,   0,   0, 0,
          0,   2
      ]
    },
    maxSetVersion: 1,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

The Question:

1. What extra packages do I have to install to enable mongodb connection?
2. Is it good option to change base image from ubuntu:jammy to node:16-alpine and install `libeigen3-dev libboost-all-dev libopencv-dev libpcl-dev zlib1g-dev libflann-dev libqhull-dev libsnappy-dev libicu-dev libglib2.0-dev libbsd-dev libpcre3-dev libbson-dev libmongoc-dev libcgal-dev` packages?
   I'm afraid node:16-alpine is optimized for only node environment, so downgrade the performance of daemon compared to ubuntu:jammy.